# Binary search on Cursor having sorted data

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a Cursor having sorted huge data. Now I want to binary search on the Cursor. But calling `moveToPosition(int position)` method takes much time which add ups huge time for binary search. I want to do binary search multiple times so instead of querying every time in `sqlite` database wants to query once and do binary search each time. How can I do fast binary search on sorted data cursor?

Comment: It doesn't seem like there are more options available, so instead of doing this with cursor try copying your data into a list and do searching over there.

Comment: But copying data in list will take a lot of memory.

Comment: This is not what cursors are designed for. Why don't you search in the database?

Comment: I am searching a range of string list every time user types in text box. If I search every time on database it slow down search. So I want to do query once do binary search every time.

Comment: you got to let go off one of them. choose either time or space. if you remember space and time are inversely protional. if want to save time use list. if space try querying the database each time. why don't you create a cursor adapter and add a filter in your adapter. though this might your answer.

Comment: try this link - http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-simpler-autocompletetextview-with-simplecursoradapter/

Comment: Adding filter doesn't help me because in filter callback I must go back to query on database instead of reusing previous cursor.